# Phantomjs creates lots of dmp files

Tags: phantomjs

Can I stop PhantomJS from creating dump files when it crashes? 
Currently, phantomjs is creating several dmp files in my /tmp folder on my server. I know that the /tmp folder is cleaned up after each reboot; however this box never gets rebooted.

Thanks,

Comment: [Known bug](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12236)

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/680062/275244) worked for me: export a variable

```
export PHANTOMJS_DISABLE_CRASH_DUMPS="on"
```